# Angular 10 : Model window is not opening in second click

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I am facing one issue with Model window. Model window is coming in background of nav bar and overlay. This is coming due to we are using third party bundle.js. that js is adding dynamic class and div under parent-container. For one class they are using position:fixed. i.e. model window is coming in background. If we use appendTo('body').model(); in that case model window is opening properly for first click but in second click it is not opening. because that model html is not reside under that component. it is showing modalImage.length = 0.

If we put model html out side of parent-container in index.html. in that case it is working fine but Angular is not support that. Angular just opening model with in the component not out side.

What should i do for this scenario? How to handle? Am i doing some thing wrong?

[image]

Index.html

```
        <body class="multi-app">
          <div id="parent-container">
            <div>
              <div>        
                <cfapp-root></cfapp-root>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
```

app.component.ts

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'cfapp-root',
          template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
```

app.rounting.module.ts

```
        const routes: Routes = [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
        ];
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        import { BuyersComponent } from "../buyers/buyers.component";

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-dashboard',
          templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
        })
        export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

          @ViewChild(BuyersComponent, { static: true }) buyerPop: BuyersComponent;
          constructor() { }

          ngOnInit(): void {
          }

          popupBuyerNetSheet(event: any) {
            this.buyerPop.openBuyerPOPUP(event);
          }

          callCountyComp(event: any){

          }
        }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
        <div class="col-6 col-xl-4 opt-box">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="box-inner h-100 bg-2 text-center"
                (click)="popupBuyerNetSheet($event)">
                <div class="box-icon d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <img src="assets/images/icons.svg" alt="" width="26">
                </div>
                <h6 class="box-title">Buyer Pop Up</h6>
                <p class="box-subtitle d-none d-xl-block">Closing Costs</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

buyer.component.ts

```
         openBuyerPOPUP(event) {
            let modalImage = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("div#BuyerPopUpHtml");
            modalImage.modal("show");
         }
```

buyer.component.html

```
         <div class="modal fade" id="BuyerPopUpHtml" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                    This is body.
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: You can increase the `z-index` of the modal. Still if you can create a working demo that would be better

Comment: That is not handle by z-index. My designer already try same. I think this should solve from jQuery. If we put model html out side of parent-container. in that case it is working fine but Angular is not support that. Angular just opening model with in the component not out side.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I was using Model window by using jQuery. but when i used NgbModule that automatically append model window with body.

install Ng Bootstrap package.

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

import NgbModule to app.module.ts file.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
   
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```